# How do I add (stamp) a graphic to EVERY slide on a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office365

How do I add a graphic (the same picture or object) to EVERY slide in a PowerPoint deck?

I don't want to use the 'Slide Master', I want to **actually** add an item on EVERY slide.

Answer (score 0):

User '[Steve Rindsberg](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/8710e173-7c59-402b-a734-2916ae7fd288)' had a very good solution to this on the Microsoft [forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-paste-text-into-multiple-powerpoint-slides/4e4946ac-0448-43ce-9964-16c14a5ae8d6).  Here is that solution with a twist.

First, save all open document(s) for safety.

### #1. Create a new 'helper' PowerPoint deck, separate from your main document.

Save the deck as a `PowerPoint Presentation with Macros (PPTM)` format.
Let's call it `TheStamper.pptm.`

You do NOT have to save your main deck into this format.

### #2. Add a Macro to the 'helper' deck.

Hit `Alt`-`F11` (just like Excel) -- then `Insert`-`Module` the following module:

```
Sub StampEmDano()
' It's up to the user to select the shape that needs to appear on every selected slide.
' Then copy it to the clipboard
' Then select the slides it's to be copied TO ( in slide sorter view )
' And finally, run this macro

Dim oSl As Slide

For Each oSl In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
    oSl.Shapes.Paste
Next
    
End Sub
```

Now **save your helper deck** (TheStamper.pptm).
You can close out of the Macro Editor with `Alt`-`F4`.

### #3. Prepare the object

- First, switch to your "main" Powerpoint deck.
- Position your desired image/object/graphic on a slide (like Slide 1) in the correct location.
- Copy [`Ctrl`-`C`] the desired image/object/graphic to the clipboard.

> **TIP:** The object will be pasted into the **same location** on every slide.

### #4. Run the macro in the main deck

> **TIP:** the below works because PowerPoint currently lets you run macros
> *from macro-enabled* PPTM documents, *in non-macro-enabled* PPTX documents.   (Excel works the same way.)

- Type `Alt`-`F8` for the Macro:Run dialog, ***OR***
- Type `Alt`-`Q` and type "Macro" for the Macro:Run dialog.
- **At the bottom of the dialog, switch "Macro in:"** to the document containing the Macro, `TheStamper.pptm.`
- Select the macro name (StampEmDano) and hit `Run`.

Comment: Nice job with the instructions.  Thanks!  There's another version here that just picks up whatever you've selected and copies it to the other slides:  https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00780_Copy_a_picture_or_other_shape_to_every_slide_in_a_presentation.htm

Comment: Very cool alternative there.  Honored you saw this -- and thank you! ☺️